# Bring correct date format in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I need date format in American Format i.e. 9/30/2018; 8/31/2018; 7/31/2018.. so on and so forth in SSIS. I have written the code in the format as

```
LEFT((DT_STR,50,1252)DATEADD("d",-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),10)
```

This is bringing date in 2018-09-30 which is not the proper format. I do have given the data type as "STRING" as the above code doesn't take "DATE/DATE-TIME" as data type.

I am trying to bring the previous month last date and hence the format currently being fetched is not right.

Any guesses?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this is a good read http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: Did you store `DATE` as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a format like this, the date parts will need to be extracted from the date and concatenated accordingly.  The expression below will convert the date to the DD/MM/YYYY format.  Since you only listed single digits for the month in your question, this example does **not** account for zeros and the length will vary.  If you want zeros added to single digit days and months, a `"0"` (with quotes) will need to be appended before the day and month.

```
RIGHT((DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("MM", DATEADD("D",-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE())), 2) 
+ "/" + RIGHT((DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("D",-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE())), 2) 
+ "/" +  (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("YYYY", DATEADD("D",-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that

```
DECLARE @AsStr  VARCHAR(10) = '2018-09-30', --If you store it as string
        @AsDate DATE = '2018-09-30'; --If you store it as date

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AsDate, 101) AsStr,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(@AsStr AS DATE), 101)  AsDate;
```

**Returns**

```
+------------+------------+
|   AsStr    |   AsDate   |
+------------+------------+
| 09/30/2018 | 09/30/2018 |
+------------+------------+
```

Or you can use `FORMAT()` function as

```
SELECT
       FORMAT(CAST(@AsStr AS DATE), 'MM/dd/yyyy') FormatStr,
       FORMAT(@AsDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') FormatDate;
```

**Returns**

```
+------------+------------+
| FormatStr  | FormatDate |
+------------+------------+
| 09/30/2018 | 09/30/2018 |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEFROMPARTS` to get the first day of the month fairly easily.  Then, you can use `DATEADD` to subtract a day, then `CONVERT` to output the 101 format which is in the form MM/DD/YYYY.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DT_STR Date = '2018-10-23'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DT_STR), MONTH(@DT_STR), 1)), 101) AS [answer]
```

Produces output:

```
answer
09/30/2018
```